# Linux: How can i extract information from the files's name?

Tags: linux, grep, find, cat

I have some files(.txt), the name are:

```
run_freq100ampl0.6offs0.8_1
run_freq100ampl0.4offs1.1_1
run_freq100ampl0.2offs1.0_1
run_freq100ampl0.4offs1.2_1
run_freq100ampl0.2offs1.1_1
run_freq100ampl0.5offs0.8_1
run_freq100ampl0.2offs1.2_1
run_freq100ampl0.4offs0.8_1
```

I want get the number of ampl, like

```
0.6
0.4
0.2
0.4
0.2
0.5
0.2
0.4
```

How can i do it with 'find', 'grep' or 'cat' in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -Po '(?<=ampl).*(?=offs)' input
```

Example:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=ampl).*(?=offs)' <<< "run_freq100ampl0.2offs1.1_1"
0.2
```

---

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/.*ampl\(.*\)offs.*/\1/' <<< "run_freq100ampl0.2offs1.1_1"
0.2
```

Comment: Thank you! But i want to show all values one time. How can i do it?

Comment: @user2862989 Either say `sed 's/.*ampl\(.*\)offs.*/\1/' filename` or `grep -Po '(?<=ampl).*(?=offs)' filename`

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F"ampl|off" '{print $2}'
0.6
0.4
0.2
0.4
0.2
0.5
0.2
0.4
```

Or using fixed position

```
awk '{print substr($0,16,3)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.txt
do
  f=${f%offs*}
  f=${f#*ampl}
  echo ${f}
done
```